# deploy react app in digitalocean using docker appspec

Tags: reactjs, deployment, digital-ocean

I need to deploy a react app in digitalocean, the deployment is success but i cannot access the website.

In console i could see https://domain_name/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png.
Also the homepage variable is not set.

my package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./src",
"lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ./src",
"clear-all": "rm -rf build node_modules",
"re-start": "rm -rf build node_modules && yarn install && yarn start",
"re-build": "rm -rf build node_modules && yarn install && yarn build"
```

},

Digital ocean appspec in app platform:

```
 alerts:
- rule: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
- rule: DOMAIN_FAILED
 ingress:
  rules:
   - component:
    name: frontend
  match:
  path:
    prefix: /
  name: frontend
  region: blr
  static_sites:
  - environment_slug: html
  github:
    branch: main
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: repo/Frontend
    name: frontend
    source_dir: /
```